# Count of distinct values from filtered column

Tags: excel, vba

I have one Excel sheet with 6000 rows. I need to delete entire rows if distinct values are less than, say, three in one particular column.

Per below example:
In column-A with the list of colours and in column-B with names.
If I filter any '**name in column-B** and in **column-A, if less than three distinct values = true** then entire row should be deleted.

Rows with name- Chary should be deleted.

```
A         B
Color   Employee
Red     Dev
blue    Dev
blue    Dev
Red     Dev
black   Dev
Red     Dev
Red     Chary
blue    Chary
blue    Chary
Red     Chary
Red     Chary
Red     Chary
```

With my code:
First I filter name in column-B then paste the filtered data new workbook and there I will remove duplicates from column-A then will get the unique count.
If the unique count is less than 3 then activate the main sheet and will delete filtered rows and loop to next name.

```vb
Sub Del_lessthan_5folois()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    t = Now()
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Sheets("VALID ARNS").Activate
    
    iCol = 2 '### criteria column
    
    Set ws = Sheets("VALID ARNS")
    Sheets("VALID ARNS").Activate
    Set rnglast = Columns(iCol).Find("*", Cells(1, iCol), , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    ws.Columns(iCol).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
    Set rngUnique = Range(Cells(2, iCol), rnglast).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    Workbooks.Add
    Set newb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    For Each strItem In rngUnique
        If strItem <> "" Then
            ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:=strItem.Value
        
            newb.Activate
        
            ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=[A1]
        
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            Dim uniq As Range
        
            Set uniq = Range("A1:S" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
           
            uniq.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=7, Header:=xlYes
    
            LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    
            Cells.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    
            Range("A1").Select
        
            wb.Activate
        
            If LastRow < "3" Then
    
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1,0).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete (xlShiftUp)
        
            End If
         
        End If
     
    Next
    ws.ShowAllData
    
    MsgBox "The entire process took! " & Format(Now() - t, "hh:mm:ss") & " Minutes"
      
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub
```

My code works in step by step debug mode but when run it skips a lot of rows.
Can this be related to *more than 6000 rows*?

How do I get the count of distinct values in **Column-A when filtered in Column-B**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly the same code that you posted as I had some troubles with it, but here's an alternative solution. I simply copy the data into another sheet (please add sheet called "Results" before you run my code), add two more columns with formulas (these will check if a given "Employee" should be deleted), filter on "TRUE" and then delete relevant rows.

From what I tested such solution seems to be faster than applying Advanced Filters, checking for unique values and then looping through the whole dataset. I hope it will work fine for your setup.

Here's the code:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim t As Variant
    Dim iCol As Long, lngLastRow As Long
    Dim wsOrig As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    t = Now()
    Set wsOrig = Sheets("VALID ARNS")
    Set wsNew = Sheets("Results")
    iCol = 2 '### criteria column

    With wsOrig
        lngLastRow = .Columns(iCol).Find("*", Cells(1, iCol), , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row
        'copy into Results sheet
        .Range("A1:B" & lngLastRow).Copy wsNew.Range("A1")
        With wsNew
            'add formulas
            .Range("C1:D1").Value = VBA.Array("Instance", "Delete?")
            .Range("C2:C" & lngLastRow).Formula = "=COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2,B2)"
            .Range("D2:D" & lngLastRow).Formula = "=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$" & lngLastRow & ",$B$2:$B$" & lngLastRow & ",B2,$C$2:$C$" & lngLastRow & ",1)<3"
            'delete when column D = TRUE
            .Range("A1:D" & lngLastRow).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="TRUE"
            .Range("D2:D" & lngLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Delete
            'clear
            .Range("A1:B" & lngLastRow).AutoFilter
            .Range("C:D").Clear
        End With
    End With

    MsgBox "The entire process took! " & Format(Now() - t, "hh:mm:ss") & " Minutes"

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
End Sub
```

"VALID ARNS" sheet:

[image]

"Results" sheet (after running the code):

[image]

**Edit:**

Another option, using `Scripting.Dictionary` functionality:

```
Public Function getUnique(ByVal rngVals As Excel.Range) As Variant()
    Dim objDictionary       As Object
    Dim rngRow              As Excel.Range
    Dim rngCell             As Excel.Range
    Dim strKey              As String

    Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each rngRow In rngVals.Rows
        For Each rngCell In rngRow.Cells
            strKey = strKey & "||" & rngCell.Text
        Next rngCell
        With objDictionary
            If Not .Exists(Key:=Mid$(strKey, 3)) Then
                Call .Add(Key:=Mid$(strKey, 3), Item:=Mid$(strKey, 3))
            End If
        End With
        strKey = ""
    Next rngRow

    getUnique = objDictionary.Keys

    Set rngVals = Nothing
    Set rngRow = Nothing
    Set rngCell = Nothing
End Function

Public Sub CountUnique()
    Dim rngVals             As Excel.Range
    Dim varUnique()         As Variant
    Dim rngCell             As Excel.Range
    Dim varTemp             As Variant

    Set rngVals = Sheet3.Range("A2:B13").SpecialCells(12)
    varUnique = getUnique(rngVals)

    For Each rngCell In rngVals.Columns(2).Cells
        varTemp = Filter(varUnique, rngCell.Text, True)
        Debug.Print rngCell.Text, UBound(varTemp) - LBound(varTemp) + 1
        Erase varTemp
    Next rngCell

    Set rngVals = Nothing
    Set rngCell = Nothing
    Erase varUnique
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Justyna MK,  Thanks for the reply. your code is just awesome it's working great thanks a lot for the code...please help me with the code if any to get distinct value count in particular column in filter mode.. its just for my knowledge im asking. thanks in advance.

Comment: Happy it works for you. Sure, I'll give it a try later today and let you know.

Comment: It looks like you cannot use `Filter` or `Advanced Filter` functionality as you are not really looking for unique values in one column - it's actually a combination of both columns (A&B) that determines if the value is unique or not. That is why you need to use `Scripting.Dictionary` functionality. I updated my code with a funciton (`getUnique`) which shows unique combinations of columns A&B, and a subroutine (`CountUnique`) which prints (in a debug mode) how many unique combinaitons are presented for each visible (filtered) row. Hope it helps.